# Wrapper size increases after adding the button

Tags: html, css

I have an image wrapper in which i want to show a button on mouse hover with a black background. I tried to do it but it added a white space to the container at the bottom, i dont know why.

HTML:

```
<div class="tour-box-wrapper" style="margin-right:45px">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="grayscale"><img src="http://static.teambuy.ca/deal/540x254/other/28165573-2014-03-03-28144457-boxhouse-10b.jpg" /></a> 
          <a><button type="button" class="view-deal-button"  >View Deal</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tour-box-wrapper
{
width:45%;
border: 1px solid #BBB;
padding:2px;
background-color: #E7E7E7;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left    bottom,from(#FFFFFF),to(#E7E7E7));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#FFFFFF,#E7E7E7);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#FFFFFF,#E7E7E7);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#FFFFFF,#E7E7E7);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#FFFFFF,#E7E7E7);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF,#E7E7E7);
float:left;
display:block;
}

.image-wrapper 
{
border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
padding:2px;
display: block;

}

.image-wrapper img
{   
width:100%;
}

a.grayscale {
display: inline-block;
background: black;
padding: 0;
}

a.grayscale img {
display: block;
}

a.grayscale:hover img
{
opacity: 0.5;
}
.view-deal-button 
{
border: none;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
left: 343px;
bottom: 36px;
background-color: #CD277B;
padding:6px;
 }

.view-deal-button a
{
color:white;
font-size:14px;
}
```

Note ignore the Javascript which i know will be used to display button on mouse enter but i just want to fix this extra space below the image and want to bring the button to the bottom right corner of the image.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9ESy/)

Comment: JSfiddle please. As a start, try setting the image to `display:block;` though.

Comment: the view deal button is the button u r talkin about?

Comment: @Paulie_D have added it already

Comment: Yes @AJ the deal button i want it at the right bottom corner

Comment: Where should the view button be shown? Next tot it? Inside the container under the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button having a position of 'relative' is what's creating the space that the bottom. It's 'mass' is affecting its parent container. If you don't want it having any 'mass', try positioning it 'absolute' relative to the parent.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the relative positioning and the bottom property.

```
 .view-deal-button {
    background-color: #CD277B;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    bottom: 36px;
    left: 343px;
    padding: 6px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Moving the button right and under the image.

```
.view-deal-button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: #CD277B;
  padding:6px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4r3p/3/

Comment: So how i move the button to the right bottom corner of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for button

```
.view-deal-button 
{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    left: 343px;
    bottom: 36px;
    background-color: #CD277B;
    padding:6px;
    margin: 0% 0% 0% -80%;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9ESy/2/)